# My wordpress website Home Page gets scattered

Tags: html, wordpress, web, wordpress-theming, website-deployment

[I have inserted the image, that how my WordPress site homepage is scattered, my other site pages are working properly but home page is not I have installed a theme.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLUXE.png)

Comment: Edit your home page and save again and remove cache. hard refresh

Answer (score 0):

Go to your elementor tools settings
Open the General tab
Regenerate CSS and sync library and save it.
See the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/CLtnnE5vJk-4

Comment: No! It dosent work.

Comment: Can you please share your website url then I can give you the right solution.